# Cannot convert ViewModel to DataModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a UserViewModel for my users. I want to use that for registration.

I do not want to use my datamodel for registration or login.

My UserViewModel is as below:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int    user_id         { get; set; } //Primary Key in user table

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Email:")]
    public string email           { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name:")]
    public string f_name          { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name:")]
    public string l_name          { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Contact Number:")]
    public string contact         { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Gender:")]
    public string gender          { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Blood Type:")]
    public string blood_type      { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Password:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password        { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Confirm Password:")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("password")]
    public string confirm_password { get; set; }
}
```

My Registration ActionMethod is as below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registration(UserViewModel uvmr)
    {
        db.users.Add(uvmr);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

My dataModel for user(user.cs) is as below:

```
public partial class user
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public user()
    {
        this.appointments = new HashSet<appointment>();
    }

    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string f_name { get; set; }
    public string l_name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string contact { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string blood_type { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<appointment> appointments { get; set; }
}
```

N.B: I have no Confirm Password column in my user table.

Now the error says cannot convert from das.Models.ViewModel.UserViewModel to das.Models.DataModel.user

What is work-around for this one?

Comment: There's no "work around" - you would need to map your view model to a new instance of your data model, either manually or with something like Automapper.

Comment: @TiesonT. can you provide any link to manual mapping?

Comment: Manual mapping: just create a `user` object and set its fields 1by1 equal to your `uvmr` object fields

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide just any object instance to `db.users.Add(uvmr);` - the `DbSet<T>.Add()` method is typed to each of your data models.

Since your models are fairly similar, converting one to the other is relatively simple:

```cs
var newUser = new user
{
    user_id = uvmr.user_id
    f_name = uvmr.f_name 
    l_name = uvmr.l_name 
    email = uvmr.email 
    contact = uvmr.contact 
    gender = uvmr.gender 
    blood_type = uvmr.blood_type 
    password = uvmr.password 
};
```

*Then* you can add the new `user` instance:

```cs
db.users.Add(newUser);
```

Assuming that you don't want to duplicate this code everytime you need to map one to the other, you can create a mapping utility - I tend to use a static class for that:

```cs
public static class Mapper
{
    public static user MapUser(UserViewModel uvmr)
    {
        return uvmr == null ? null : new user
        {
            user_id = uvmr.user_id
            f_name = uvmr.f_name 
            l_name = uvmr.l_name 
            email = uvmr.email 
            contact = uvmr.contact 
            gender = uvmr.gender 
            blood_type = uvmr.blood_type 
            password = uvmr.password 
        };
    }
}
```

Then you could do something like:

```cs
var user = Mapper.MapUser(uvmr);
```

Of course, utilities like [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) can do the same, and in your case might be simpler - AutoMapper, even without any setup code, will try to map properties with the same name.

As an aside, your class names and properties are currently violating Microsoft's naming conventions - I'd suggest reading the [Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)  if this is code meant to shared outside of your organization.

Comment: So, if I go with the first method I'll have to duplicate the mapping in each and every action method, whenever I need to store something on the user table?

Comment: Yes. Your only other alternative is to implement conversion operators - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators - although you'd still need to convert the view model to the data model.